# Open a specific Activity of app from a web link android

Tags: android, android-studio, deep-linking, intentfilter

I tried almost all the methods that displayed regarding the query and deeplinking, but none of them worked for me.
This is the type of the link which is to be opened from an android browser

```
"http://www.udmy.com/view?jb_id=J091107"
```

How can I start specific activity of my application passing "jb_id=J091107" if this URL is accessed from mobile browser?

Is it possible to get "jb_id=J091107" ?

I also want to open playstore link if app is not installed in phone.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [Add Android App Links](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html)

Comment: this worked fine..thanks a lot.. :)